# C++11 list initialization weird behaviour on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: arrays, c++11, initialization, destructor, unique-ptr

I'm trying to pass an array to a function and to prevent writing "std::unique_ptr" each time and to make inline construction possible, I introduce a typedef (ItemList) to alias the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base ctor" << std::endl;
    };

    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base dtor" << std::endl;
    };
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Base> ItemList[];

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
    T val;
public:
    Derived(T i)
    {
        val = i;
        std::cout << "Derived ctor" << val << std::endl;
    };

    ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived dtor" << val << std::endl;
    };
};

void dummyFunc(ItemList)
{

}

void testFunc()
{
    dummyFunc(ItemList{
        std::make_unique<Derived<int>>(2),
        std::make_unique<Derived<float>>(3.0f)
    });
}

//Entry point
int main()
{
    testFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

This works as intended in a Debug build and prints;

```
Base ctor
Derived ctor2
Base ctor
Derived ctor2
Derived dtor2
Base dtor
Derived dtor2
Base dtor
```

So far so good. But when I build this in Release mode (with all native compilers) I get;

```
Base ctor
Derived ctor2
Base ctor
Derived ctor3
Derived dtor2
Base dtor
```

The second item in the array is not getting destructed upon exiting the lifecycle of the array.
The only way to make it work as I expect, is using a C++03 style initialization or debug mode;

```
ItemList tmpList = {
    std::make_unique<Derived<int>>(2),
    std::make_unique<Derived<float>>(2.0f)
};

dummyFunc(tmpList);
```

This results in the intended behavior (all destructors called).

I have not tested this with any other compiler yet but is this the expected behaviour? What am I doing wrong or am I missing something?

**Update:**

Interestingly dtors are called as expected with Base instances;

```
dummyFunc(ItemList{
    std::make_unique<Base>(),
    std::make_unique<Base>()
});
```

Outputs;

```
Base ctor
Base ctor
Base dtor
Base dtor
```

And just initializing the array (without function call) behaves the same as with the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to Visual Studio 2015. This is probably an implementation bug in VS2013 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually does not build with g++ 6.2, and the error is explicit enough to explain why you don't get the expected behavior:

```
foo.cc:44:15: error: taking address of temporary array
     dummyFunc(ItemList{
               ^~~~~~~~~
         std::make_unique<Derived<int>>(2),
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         std::make_unique<Derived<float>>(3.0f)
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     });
```

A simple fix would be to use:

`using ItemList = std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<Base>>;`

instead of an array.

**Update**: the behavior of VS might be the correct one:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result
>   is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Interesting... It compiles both on win and mac default compilers. Not sure about the release behavior on mac but will check. Havent tried your solution yet. On the other hand I am not sure if it should really complain about using a temporary array. It is my problem, a warning would be a better behavior. Should check the standard on this behavior.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem taking the address of an rvalue is illegal, cf the standard: `The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id.` About the behavior of VS in release, I updated my answer.

Comment: This still does not explain the behavior. If it is converted into a pointer to first element then why the first item is destructed? I dont get it. Im okay if the object gets destroyed before being passed to the func but it should be destroyed since it is allocated on the stack.

Comment: You can try without the call to dummyFunc, just initialize the variable to bypass the compiler error.